# Russian verb + "то"

Tags: грамматика

Когда и почему частица "то" добавляется к глаголам. См. пример:

> Ты и ешь-то и пьёшь-то не вовремя, не тогда, когда есть и пить
>   хочется, а от скуки.

Comment: i don't think there's a rule to this which can be learned, this is a purely feeling thing as in Russian its use isn't formalized, there's opinion that this particle and its dialectical variants serve as a definite article, similar to Bulgarian, however unlike in Bulgarian it can join almost any major part of speech and not only nouns and adjectives

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Частица "то" дополнительно употребляется после различных частей речи (**и после глаголов тоже**) ***для подчёркивания и выделения в предложении слова, к которому относится***: Слушать-то слушал, да ничего не понял. Однако мост-то наш каков. Неужто-таки и грешные-то молитвы мои не доходили. Как-то милые в дальнем краю? Я-то понимаю. Ночь-то какая тёплая! Где-то он сейчас? Что дальше-то делать будешь?

The particle " то " is additionally used after various parts of speech (**and after verbs too** ) ***for underlining and highlighting in the sentence of the word to which it belongs***.